# Omit an object from a union of objects

Tags: typescript

A library I use defines a type as this:

```
export declare type LogInResult = {
    type: 'cancel';
} | {
    type: 'success';
    accessToken: string | null;
    idToken: string | null;
    refreshToken: string | null;
    user: GoogleUser;
};
```

I want to create a type `SuccessLoginResult` by omitting the `{ type: 'cancel' }` object, is this possible?

Some pseudocode I tried didn't work:

```
type SuccessLoginResult = Omit<LogInResult, { type: 'cancel' }>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Exclude`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) for that *(but keep reading)*:

```typescript
type SuccessLogInResult = Exclude<LogInResult, {type: 'cancel'}>;
```

It creates a type by excluding the second type from the first (union) type.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4g9nA5gGwgVQM4QE5QLxQDeAvgNwBQokUAMkgJIB2AShBgK7LD5HlT9QqEAFxQA5AGMAhowkRkYisSgAfXgMHgR4jhLkYMivgKl62GACpwA1hEaiMwbAEtGiVVEadkFDc4AmVrb2UI4ubh5eyD7G-NgQAGbxGAAWQXYOTq7ualExGuxY2KLwSKiYOEoUQlAAyuxmBnSITKwcXDwAogAeEsjs-hAAPM2tbJzAADREQqKSMnIKxAB8pEA)

It looks like you can use [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) as well, which might be more intuitive:

```typescript
type SuccessLogInResult = Extract<LogInResult, {type: 'success'}>;
```

I would have thought I'd have to include more than just the `type` in the second type argument there, but apparently not, as it seems to work:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA4g9nA5gGwgVQM4QE5QLxQDeAvgNwBQokUAMkgJIB2AShBgK7LD5HlT9QqEAFxQA5AGMAhowkRkYisSgAfXgMHgR4jhLkYMivgKl62GACpwA1hEaiMwbAEtGiVVEadkFDc4AmVrb2UI4ubh5eyD7G-NgQAGbxGAAWQXYOTq7ualExGuxY2KLwSKiYOEoUQlAAyuxmBnSITKwcXDwAogAeTqbAADzNrWycwAA0REKiYrr6hsQAfKRAA)

Comment: Wow this is brilliant, thank you. The docs have everything just need to dig. I like your `Extract` approach more because we can provide a partial. If I use `Exclude` it seems I have to provide the full, and the library might change overtime to include more in the `{ type: 'cancel' }` so the `Exclude` will fail. Thank you!

Comment: @Noitidart - You're welcome! The TypeScript docs are getting better all the time, though there's still a lot missing from them. I don't see your point about `Exclude` (if I add more to the type, I don't have to add more to the `Exclude`) but FWIW I'm with you -- I'd use the `Extract` version anyway, since to me it's more intuitive.

Comment: Oh! `Exclude` also works with partial. Wow thanks an answer within an answer! This solution needs a double accept lol.